# Image shear in WPF

Tags: wpf, image, transformation

I am trying to shear an Image in WPF (C#) using pure XAML. I have used transformations such as skew, scale and matrix but I am not getting the result as I want. Following is the code I am using

```
         <Image Source="G:\Demo\virtualization\virtualization\img3.bmp" Stretch="Fill" Height="70" Width="240" Margin="0,170,-312,-29" >
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <MatrixTransform Matrix="1,.1,-4.2,1,0,0" />
                    <!--<ScaleTransform ScaleX=".2" ScaleY=".6"/>-->
                </TransformGroup>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
```

With the above code, below is the similar effect that I am getting:

```
   /----/
  /    /
 /    /
/----/
```

But I want following effect:

```
     /---\
    /     \
   /       \
  /---------\
```

Due to new user, I am not allowed to post Images right now...

Thanks

***EDIT:***

I have tried viewport3d to get this effect. Following is the code:

```
<Grid>
        <Image Source="G:\Demo\virtualization\virtualization\2.jpg"/>
        <Viewport3D Name="mainViewport" ClipToBounds="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="300">
            <Viewport3D.Camera>
                    <PerspectiveCamera Position="0, 0, 20"  />
            </Viewport3D.Camera>
            <Viewport2DVisual3D>
                <Viewport2DVisual3D.Transform>
                    <MatrixTransform3D Matrix="1,0,0,0 
                                               0,1,0,0 
                                               0,0,1,0
                                               0,0,0,1" />
                </Viewport2DVisual3D.Transform>

                <Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
                    <MeshGeometry3D Positions="-1,1,0 -1,-1,0 1,-1,0 1,1,0"
                            TextureCoordinates="0,0 0,1 1,1 1,0" TriangleIndices="0 1 2 0 2 3"/>
                </Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>

                <Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
                    <DiffuseMaterial Viewport2DVisual3D.IsVisualHostMaterial="True" Brush="White"/>
                </Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
                <Grid>

                <Image Source="G:\Demo\virtualization\virtualization\img3.bmp"/>
                </Grid>

            </Viewport2DVisual3D>

            <ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <DirectionalLight Color="#FFFFFFFF" Direction="0,-1,-1"/>
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
        </Viewport3D>
    </Grid>
```

I am using matrix transformation to get the effect.
However I am looking to alternate ways to get this effect May be rotating the camera of viewport.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot achieve this kind of effect with linear transformation (mathematically impossible).

You could get this effect with WPF 3D.

Comment: thanks but could you point me some code or exapmle? it would be really good for me

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this effect with a custom pixel shader.

Download a copy of Shazzam (it's free) and check out the paperfold sample (shazzam-tool.com).  While it's not exactly the shear effect you showed in your question, it is close.

Have you worked with shaders before? If you want to use a custom shader I have a prototype shear effect that I worked on a couple months ago.  I can clean up the HLSL and post it here.

### Edit

Shazzam contains a tutorial section and about 80 sample shaders.  That's a good place to start.  The hardest part about using custom shaders is that you have to learn a new language (HLSL).

There is a list of shader articles at http://blog.shazzam-tool.com/index.php/shader-articles/

Comment: Thanks if you could teach me something about custom pixel shader or point me in the right direction will be great. I am confused what to chose and what to not. I mean I have many directions to go ie. Image transformations, viewport3d transformation, camera rotations.. etc etc. But I am not be able to find the best solution.